# Blink animation in the Shape of Circle

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I have a circular Shape View in android, I want to have the Blink animation of it.

Here is my layout.xml

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/circle"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/solid_circle"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Drawable/solid_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>

</shape>
```

The above code will show a Circular View. I wanted the circle to be blinking. Here is the code where I use Blink Animation for the Circular View.

```
    ObjectAnimator objAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mCircle, "backgroundColor", Color.WHITE, ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent), Color.WHITE);
    objAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    objAnimator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    objAnimator.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    objAnimator.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    objAnimator.start();
```

The problem with it is , it is Blinking the Circle in the form of a rectangle, can we have the Blink Animation in the form of a Circle ? How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are animating `backgroundColor` of a view, it is going to animate background which is rectangle/square

Instead you have to implement `alpha`animation

So animator is :

```
    ObjectAnimator objAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCircle, "alpha",0f,1f);
    objAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    objAnimator.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    objAnimator.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    objAnimator.start();
```

I Hope this is what you want.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, i get an exception "java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer", any idea why?